# use $x variable in with cut command parameter

Tags: bash

i have this bash line

```
current_part= `echo "${lines[$i]}"  | cut -d , -f$x`
```

is it possible to use variable $x with cut's parameter -f ?
i want -f1, -f2, -f3 and so on with each iteration of $x

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible:

```
$ lines=("abc,def" "foo,bar")

$ x=1
$ echo "${lines[1]}" | cut -d, -f$x
foo

$ x=2
$ echo "${lines[1]}" | cut -d, -f$x
bar
```

However this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)